# Android: Pantalla completa para pantallas como iPhone X - Huawei P20

Tags: android, activity, screen

buenas a todos!
Queria saber como configurar una *Activity* en fullscreen para pantallas como las de los huawei p20 o iPhone X.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento cuando configure la *Activity* en fullscreen se ve como lo que esta color verde, el resto de la pantalla, queda en negro (No puedo sacar un screen por que se ve rectangular)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna forma de completar la pantalla?
Gracias!

Comment: según lo que estoy viendo ya estas a full screen y así es comos e ve, en la primera imagen la barra de estados tiene el color de fondo transparente por lo que se ve como si la pantalla completa incluyera esta sección pero en realidad no es así, quizás para obtener el resultado que quieres lo que necesitas es ocultar la barra de estados

Comment: Lo unico que necesitaba era darle un color a la barra de notificacion, lo tenia en color negro y no lo sabia